# Display items of collection sequentially with delay - WinForms

Tags: winforms, windows

I'm trying to do this on **Windows Application.**

Can any one help how I can read two items at one instance from collection (for say, Products). Again two items after one minute and so on?

More Info:
Collection of Products

1. Product1
2. Product2
3. Product3
4. Product4

I have to fetch first two products and display on the UI.After a minute or so, display remaining two products. After this, again display the first two products. Hope I'm understable here.

I have been using Linq's skip() and take(). Couldn't find a way. I'm going crazy how do I do this.

Comment: What went wrong when you used skip and take? Could you give a little more info as to where you're going wrong and what you need help with?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm using the following query which returns me zero (0) results. Please read the lines below the list of products for exactly what i need to do.                                       var copyOfCars = from cars in carItems.Take(2) select cars;              Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is trying for the same, here is how I was able to resolve:

```
IEnumerable<Car> carItems = c.GetCarInfo();//GetCarInfo() is service method which gives me carItems.

int noOfCars = 0;
if (noOfCars >= carItems.Count())
{
    noOfCars = 0;
}

IEnumerable<Car> carsToDisplay = from cars in carItems.Skip(noOfCars).Take(2)
                                 select cars;
noOfCars += 2;
```

Along with it, used timer control.

If anyone has better solution, please update here.